# Can I use dimensional regularization with this integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, dimensional-regularization

I would like to extract the divergence of this integral in 4d Euclidean space:

$$\int d^4z \frac{1}{(x-z)^4}\tag{1}$$

This divergence is expected to cancel with other divergences, which I got using dimensional regularization. I know how to extract the log divergence of $(1)$ using a cutoff, but then I guess I have to use a correspondence between divergences

$$\log \epsilon \longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{\omega-2}\tag{2}$$

as done [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003055) (at the bottom of p.11). I am not so fond of this correspondence, and would love to extract the divergence of $(1)$ with dimensional regularization if that is possible, so to be consistent with my other results.

When I try to do regular dimensional regularization, here is what happens:

$$\begin{align}\int d^{2\omega}z \frac{1}{\left[(x-z)^2\right]^{2\omega-2}} &= \int d^{2\omega}z \frac{1}{\left[(x-z)^2(x-z)^2 \right]^{\omega-1}} \\ &= \frac{\Gamma(\omega-2)\Gamma^2(1)}{\Gamma^2(\omega-1)\Gamma(2)} \frac{\pi^\omega}{(x-x)^{\omega-2}} \tag{3}\end{align}$$

The integral was performed using Feynman parametrization and an integral in the appendix of the QFT book by Ramond. This expression is ambiguous about the divergence, since $\Gamma(\omega-2)$ diverges at $\omega-2$, while it is not clear what the behavior of $1/(x-x)^{\omega-2}$ is. Indeed, if I expand the result with $\epsilon=\omega-2$, Mathematica returns:

$$\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon)}{0^\epsilon} \approx \frac{1}{\epsilon} + \infty + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)\tag{4}$$

I think the problem may be resolved by adding a $+i\epsilon$ somewhere, but I am not sure how to proceed. In any case, the result that I am expecting to find comes out when I set $1/(x-x)^{\omega-2} = 1$

Comment: Is $z$ a four-vector? I'm confused since it seems like you can just take change integration variables directly to $z \rightarrow z + x$ immediately in your original expression, but then the integral is zero in dim reg.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Yes $x$ and $z$ are 4-vectors... How could the integral be zero? The integral $\int d^4z/z^4$ is logarithmically divergent.

Comment: Does that mean that dim reg "does not see" the logarithmic divergence? I've heard some people say that before. If that is true, how is the correspondence $(2)$ justified?

Comment: Or wait, now I am not sure anymore: is the integral given in $(1)$ logarithmically divergent, or do the UV and IR divergences cancel each other?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322076/

Comment: What exactly is $1/(x - x)$? It doesn't look right. The whole point of regularization is to make all quantities finite for $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Right, that is precisely the problem. Using the standard integrals of Ramond in $(3)$ leads to that result, but I think that is because the exchange of $d\alpha$ and $d^4z$ after using Feynman parametrization is not allowed unless the integral is defined, which is not the case here. This step is explained in the related post. I think now that this integral is $0$ as pointed out by Seth above. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case could you please expand that step carefully in your answer so that we can look for a mistake together?

Comment: The "identity" $\int_0^{\infty} dz \, z^{d-1-\alpha} = 0$ is forced on you by the properties of dimensional regularization under scale changes. One way to think of it is that dimensional regularization will effectively cancel the IR and UV divergences coming from small and large $z$ respectively, which I think some older answers on Stack Exchange have pointed out. I can write out a full answer with some details if that would be clearer.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt If you think that this is necessary, it would be nice, but I think that the answer given by Salvatore Baldino in the post that I linked in the previous comments is precisely showing that. In that answer, it is also explicitly stated that the interchange of $d\alpha$ and $d^4z$ is allowed when there is "an open set in the complex plane where the integral makes sense and is convergent". Hence this, I think, solves the issue of the OP.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov I was going to do that, but after writing my last comment I think that it is not needed anymore. The way I compute the integral using dim reg is erroneous, and thus the $1/(x-x)^{\omega-2}$ does not make sense as you pointed out. The right way to proceed is given in the post that I linked above, and results in a cancellation of IR and UV divergences.

Comment: I'll just briefly add my interpretation of this "cancellation of IR and UV divergences." I write $\int_0^{\infty} dz \, z^{d-1-\alpha} = \int_0^{1} dz \, z^{d-1-\alpha} +\int_1^{\infty} dz \, z^{d-1-\alpha}$. The first integral is evaluated in the convergent regime $\alpha < d$, obtaining $1/(d-\alpha)$. The second is evaluated in its convergent regime $\alpha > d$ obtaining $1/(\alpha-d)$. So the sum of the two is zero! This should just be interpreted an a mnemonic; the real "proof" is that $\int d^dz \, F(\lambda z) = |\lambda|^{-d}\int d^dz \, F(z)$ is an assumption of dim reg.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt In your first integral, is $d$ the number of dimensions? I am not immediately seeing how the expression you wrote relates to the integral $\int_0^\infty dz\ z^{-1}$, unless $d=0$ and $\alpha\approx 0$.

Comment: I am showing that $\int \frac{d^{d}z}{|z|^{\alpha}} \propto \int_0^{\infty} dz \, z^{d-1-\alpha} = 0$ for *all* choices of $d$ and $\alpha$. This includes your integral, where $\alpha = 4$ and $d = 2 \omega$, as a special case.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt I see, that's clear now. Thank you very much!