# Massless limits, dimensional regularization, and discontinuous beta functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

I am confused about how to interpret the apparently discontinuity which can arise in the massless limit of dimensionally regulated integrals.

My questions are illustrated by the following example:

Consider the three-point amplitude ${\cal A}_3$ for the Lorentz-violating, effective field theory
$${\cal L}=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2-\frac{\lambda_3}{\Lambda^2} \dot{\phi}(\vec{\nabla}\phi)^2 \quad ({\rm mostly \ plus \ signature})$$
where $\dot{\phi}=\partial_t\phi$ and $(\vec{\nabla}\phi)^2=\delta^{ij}\partial_{i}\phi\partial_{j}\phi$.

The tree-level contribution to the amplitude is ${\cal A}_3^{\rm tree}\sim \lambda_3 \frac{\omega_1\omega_2\omega_3}{\Lambda^2}$ while the one-loop contribution is of the schematic form
$${\cal A}_{3}^{\rm one-loop}\sim \frac{\lambda_3^3}{\Lambda^6}\int\frac{{\rm d}^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{F_9[p_i,k]}{(k^2+m^2)((k+p_1)^2+m^2)((k-p_2)^2+m^2)}$$
where $p^{\mu}_i=(\omega_i, \vec{p}_i)$ are the momenta of the on-shell states and $F_6[p_i,k]$ is some 9th-order function of momenta.  The result of the integral includes, among other terms,

$${\cal A}_{3}^{\rm one-loop}\supset \lambda_3^3\frac{F_7[\omega_i]}{\Lambda^6}\times (\frac{c_1}{\epsilon}+c_2\ln\left( m^2/\mu^2)\right) $$

as computed in dimensional regularization, schematically. $F_7[\omega_i]$ is some 7-th order function of the $\omega_i$.  Only $m^2$ can can appear in the logarithm since 3-pt kinematics of the free action fix all momenta contractions to be $\propto m^2$.

The divergence corresponds to some ${\cal L}_{\rm ct}\sim \frac{\lambda_7}{\Lambda^6}(\partial^7 \phi^3)$ counterterm whose coefficient runs due to the above logarithm:

$$\beta(\lambda_7)\sim \lambda_3^3$$

**Question:** what happens in the (technically natural) massless limit of the theory? The naive massless limit of the above is divergent.  However, as documented on this site (e.g. in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322076/dimensional-regularization-and-massless-integrals)) and elsewhere,  the massless limit of dimensionally regulated integrals is not a continuous limit, generally.  In particular, since the integral is scale-less in the massless limit, one would expect that the above contribution to ${\cal A}_{3}^{\rm one-loop}$ strictly vanishes when $m=0$, meaning that

$$\beta(\lambda_7)\sim \theta(m^2)\lambda_3^3$$

with $\theta$ the usual Heaviside function.

**Is this the right result?**  I am not familiar with other examples where such discontinuities in $\beta$-functions arise.  It feels physically incorrect.