# Tadpole diagram in one-loop QCD gluon self-energy renormalization

Tags: renormalization, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

I am trying to study QCD renormalization at 1-loop order. So, when I take into account the gluon self-energy corrections, the book I am studying from says that there are three diagrams who contribute to the amplitude, and they are:

[image]

But other sources include also a fourth diagram, a tadpole-like one:

[image]

This seems to me a well-constructed diagram, because in the QCD Lagrangian there is the four-gluon vertex. Since the fourth diagram is not even mentioned in my book, I tried to prove that it gives no contribution to the gluon self-energy but I couldn't. Is it true? If yes (and I think it must be, otherwise the result presented in the book of the one-loop field-strength renormalization constant $Z_3$ is dead wrong), is there an easy way to prove it?

Comment: You can prove it directly by writing down the integral and seeing that it vanishes due to being a scaleless integral.

Comment: Suggestion: Consider to call it a self-loop diagram for clarity.

Comment: What do you mean when you say scaleless? Doing the calculation, I arrived to a point where (if they are correct, and they looked so to me) the amplitude is proportional to $$ \delta^{ab} \eta_{\alpha \beta} \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2+i\varepsilon}$$ Are you suggesting I should take the integral to be zero because it doesn't contain the mass term in the denominator?

Comment: See here [Dimensional Regularization and Massless Integrals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322076/23615)