# Massless tadpole integrals in dimensional regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, regularization, dimensional-regularization

I'm trying to prove the following:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty x^a dx = 0, \hspace{2pt} \forall a\in \mathbb{R}. 
\end{equation}
This should work in dimensional regularization. I found a lot of answers in phisycs stack exchange, but they were only for specific cases (i.e. $\frac{1}{x^2}$, $\frac{1}{x^3}$), but I'm not able to adapt them in the general case.

Comment: I really do not understand the question, $a$ should at least be negative for this to make sense, otherwise no matter the dimension the integral will be diverging. Also it feels like you will need something else to regularize the IR ($x \sim 0$) somehow

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136424/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322076/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I suggest reading Chapter 4 in "Renormalization" by J.C. Collins.

Comment: @AlmostClueless Thanks I think this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result that in dimensional regularization all scale-less integrals vanish is basically a consistency relation. In order to give a precise meaning to dimensional regularization we need to define some functional$^1$
$$\mathcal F_d[f] = \int \text{d}^d\mathbf p f(\mathbf p )$$
that fulfills all needed requirements. A natural choice of requirements (in order to make contact to actual integration) is given by
$$
\mathcal F_d[a f + b g]= a\mathcal F_d[ f ] + b\mathcal F_d[g]\quad (\text{linearity})
$$
$$
\mathcal F_d[f(s\times \circ)]= s^{-d}\times\mathcal F_d[f(\circ)]\quad \forall s\in\mathbb R\quad (\text{scaling})
$$
$$
\mathcal F_d[f(\circ + \mathbf q)]= \mathcal F_d[f(\circ)]\quad \forall \mathbf q \in\mathbb R^d\quad (\text{translation})
$$
Now you need to check if such a funcional exists that for integer $d$ is compatible with integration. Let us assume you have done this and found that everything works out in a consistent manner (see Ref.[1]). You find for arbitrairy $s,\alpha$ and $d$
$$
\int \text{d}^d \mathbf p (\mathbf p ^2)^\alpha
= \int \text{d}^d \mathbf p ((s\mathbf p) ^2)^\alpha s^{-2\alpha}
=s^{-2\alpha}\times \int \text{d}^d \mathbf p ((s\mathbf p )^2)^\alpha
\stackrel {\text{(scaling)}}{=}s^{-2\alpha-d}\times\int \text{d}^d \mathbf p (\mathbf p ^2)^\alpha
$$
Thus, given the definition of our functional is self-consistant, the scaleless integral vanishes.

---

$^1$: Note that at this point the notation using the integral sign and all that is just by the (a priori unjustified) requirement to make contact to integration later on.

Resources:

[1] "Renormalization", by J.C. Collins