# Integrals of the form $\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{1}{k^{2n}}$ in $D=4-2\varepsilon$ dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, integration, regularization

In a massless theory we often get integrals of the form 
$$\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{1}{k^{2n}} \tag{*}$$
where $D=4-2\varepsilon$. I have tried to calculate this in two ways in Minkowski space and in Euclidean space. With the former I would be integrating
$$\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{1}{(k^2+i\varepsilon')^n}$$ 
but in this case I appear to get a factor of $1/(\varepsilon')^\epsilon$ in my final answer (for the case of $n=2$) in which I can't take $\varepsilon'\rightarrow 0$. In the Euclidean case I get an intergral of the form: 
$$\int^\infty_0 t^{\varepsilon/2-1}$$
which as far as I can tell diverges for $\varepsilon\gt 0$ (which it is). Thus my question is as follows: What is the standard and easiest way to calculate (*) ideally based only on Feynman parametrization, Schwinger parametrization and guassian integrals?

Comment: In dim reg, the value of this integral is just zero. (Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136424/).)

Comment: related question by OP: [Renormalization of a Feynman diagram with zero bare mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373768/84967).

Comment: See Collins "Renormalization" for a discussion of dimensional regularization, including this particular integral.